# Show that $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

I have problem in showing that $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic as a ring to the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* An endomorphism of $\mathbb Q$ is determined by the image of $1$.

Here are some details:

> Let $\sigma$ be an endomorphism of $\mathbb Q$ and consider $x=m/n \in \mathbb Q$. Then $m\sigma(1)=\sigma(m)=\sigma(nx)=n\sigma(x)$, and so $\sigma(m/n)=\sigma(1)(m/n)$. This gives us an explicit ring isomorphism $f: \mathbb Q \to End(\mathbb Q)$ defined by $f(q)(x)=qx$. The hint proves that $f$ is surjective. $f$ is injective because $\mathbb Q$ is a field. You need to verify that $f$ is indeed a ring isomorphism.

Comment: Okey, so suppose that $\sigma(1) = q$, where $\sigma$ is one of the endomorphisms and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, then what is the value of $\sigma(m/n)$, where $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I cannot get the results in case of module theory.

Comment: @michael, see my edited answer for the details.

Comment: I have followed your answer, but there are still doubts:

1.

Comment: I have followed your answer, but there are still doubts:

1. You wrote that $m\sigma (1)=\sigma (m)=\sigma (nx)=n\sigma (x)$, but I find it correct, but to obtain $\sigma(x)$ you have to divide both sides by $n$ but $\mathbb{Q}$ is in our case only additive group.

2. You the answer $\sigma (1)(m/n)$ but if $\sigma(1)$ is not integer then we have multiplication of two elements from $Q$ but since in our case $Q$ is additive group, we cannot do multiplication.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @michael, the *only* element $y\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $m\sigma (1)=ny$ is $y=σ(1)(m/n)$.

Comment: @Ihf And what about the socond doubt? If $\sigma(1)$ goes into something that is not in $\mathbb{Z}$ and we cannot multiply in additive group $\mathbb{Q}$, so what would the answer be?

Comment: @michael, the whole point of the argument is that multiplication in $\mathbb Q$ is essentially repeated addition.

Comment: @Ihf Ok, but if I had $\sigma(1)=1/k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, what answer will I obtain? In that case I cannot see any repeated summation. Sorry for the problem :)